# Python pandas dataframe to_csv with NaNs instead of repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a header DataFrame `df_h`

```
df_h = pd.DataFrame({'k':[1,2],'h1':['a','d'],'h2':['b','e'],'h3':['c','f']})

    k  h1  h2  h3
0   1   a   b   c
2   2   d   e   f
```

and a detail DataFrame `df_d`

```
df_d = pd.DataFrame({'k':[1,1,2,2],'d1':[10,11,12,13],'d2':[20,21,22,23],'d3':[30,31,32,33]})

    k  d1  d2  d3
0   1  10  20  30
1   1  11  21  31
2   2  12  22  32
3   2  13  23  33
```

Then I left joined them in `df` on `k`

```
df = df_h.merge(df_d, how='left', on='k')

    k  h1  h2  h3  d1  d2  d3
0   1   a   b   c  10  20  30
1   1   a   b   c  11  21  31
2   2   d   e   f  12  22  32
2   2   d   e   f  13  23  33
```

I want `to_csv` it, but I need it to end up in this way:

```
    k  h1  h2  h3  d1  d2  d3
0   1   a   b   c  10  20  30
1                  11  21  31
2   2   d   e   f  12  22  32
2                  13  23  33
```

with no repeated `df_h` rows.

Is there an option on `to_csv` or what do I need to do on `df` to make it look that way?

**Notes.**

There may be repeated values on `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `d1`, `d2`, or `d3`.

`k`is not repeated on `df_h`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace duplicate values across columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907315/replace-duplicate-values-across-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your result, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to apply your mask and `.loc` accessor to update:

```
cols = ['k', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3']
df.loc[df.duplicated(cols), cols] = ''

#    k h1 h2 h3  d1  d2  d3
# 0  1  a  b  c  10  20  30
# 1              11  21  31
# 2  2  d  e  f  12  22  32
# 2              13  23  33
```

Then just use `df.to_csv()` as normal.