# Drop or replace values within duplicate rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame `df` where some rows are duplicates with respect to a subset of columns:

```
A    B     C
1    Blue  Green
2    Red   Green
3    Red   Green
4    Blue  Orange
5    Blue  Orange
```

I would like to remove (or replace with a dummy string) values for duplicate rows with respect to `B` and `C`, without deleting the whole row, ideally producing:

```
A    B     C
1    Blue  Green
2    Red   Green
3    NaN   NaN
4    Blue  Orange
5    Nan   NaN
```

As per this thread: [Replace duplicate values across columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907315/replace-duplicate-values-across-columns-in-pandas) I've tried using `pd.Series.duplicated`, however I can't get it to work with duplicates in a subset of columns.

I've also played around with:

```
is_duplicate = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['B','C'])]
df = df.where(is_duplicated==True, 999)  # 999 intended as a placeholder that I could find-and-replace later on
```

However this replaces almost every row with `999` in each column - so clearly I'm doing something wrong. I'd appreciate any advice on how to proceed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['B','C']), ['B','C']] = np.nan` seems to work for me.

Edited to include @ALollz and @macaw_9227 correction.

Comment: If you do `df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['B','C']),['B','C'] = np.NaN` you keep the values of 'A' and onlly remove 'B' and 'C'

Answer (score 2):

Let me share with you how I used to confront those kind of challenges in the beginning. Obviously, there are quicker ways (a one-liner) but for the sake of the answer, let's do it on a more intuitive level (later, you'll see that you can do it in one line).

So here we go...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"B":['Blue','Red','Red','Blue','Blue'],"C":['Green','Green','Green','Orange','Orange']})
```

which result in

[image]

**Step 1: identify the duplication:**

For this, I'm simply adding another (facilitator) column and asking with True/False if B and C are duplicated.

```
df['IS_DUPLICATED']= df.duplicated(subset=['B','C'])
```

[image]

**Step 2: Identify the indexes of the 'True' IS_DUPLICATED:**

```
dup_index = df[df['IS_DUPLICATED']==True].index
```

result: `Int64Index([2, 4], dtype='int64')`

**Step 3: mark them as Nan:**

```
df.iloc[dup_index]=np.NaN
```

[image]

**Step 4: remove the IS_DUPLICATED column:**

```
df.drop('IS_DUPLICATED',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address this in detail! I tried implementing this in a more complex dataframe (i.e. with more columns that the one described above) and it seems to preserve the row, but deletes values in all columns (i.e. not just the specified subset)

Comment: @Lyam, with pleasure :-) if this analysis works on this sample dataframe, it should work on the bigger dataframe. I suspect that something is inconsistent with the indexes - check on your end if you got it right. Again, if it works on this set it should work on the entire set. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will using

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']].mask(df.duplicated(['B','C']))
df
Out[141]: 
   A     B       C
0  1  Blue   Green
1  2   Red   Green
2  3   NaN     NaN
3  4  Blue  Orange
4  5   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: If I would like to change the duplicates to another value (say: 'DUPLI') instead of 'NaN', how would you do this?