# Replace duplicated values across different columns in pandas with '0'

Tags: python, pandas

I have `pandas dataframe` like this (10 columns and thousands of rows):

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
     a    c     a    d    b    f    a    c    g     b
     b    g     i    k    l    r    k    b    m     l
```

It has duplicates. i want to replace duplicates with (0) across the rows and keep only the first occurrence. So, the result would be like this:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
     a    c     0    d    b    f    0    0    g     0
     0    0     i    k    l    r    0    0    m     0
```

The values in the dataframe have type "`object`". I am using python 3.5.

I found a solution in [Replace duplicate values across columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907315/replace-duplicate-values-across-columns-in-pandas) but it didn't work for me. No replacements happened.

Any other ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can `stack` to get a series, check that series for `duplicated`, `unstack` the series and mask:

```
df.mask(df.stack().duplicated().unstack(),0)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
0    a    c    0    d    b    f    0    0    g     0
1    0    0    i    k    l    r    0    0    m     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't this work?

```
is_duplicate = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)
print(df.where(~is_duplicate, 0))
```

Works fine for me:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
0    a    c    0    d    b    f    0    0    g     0
1    b    g    i    k    l    r    0    0    m     0
```

Comment: because then `duplicated` is applied on each row separately. That is, the first `b` in second row is not a duplicate, which is not OP wants.